# Correct use of properties and auto implemented properties?

Tags: c#, properties

I'm only at chapter 5 in "Essential C#" and not sure if i understand the difference correctly. I tried to make the model below to test one instance of everything in the properties chapter - and it works - but is the example acceptable use of the two ways one can implement properties or are there better ways?

```
using MarkdownSharp; // StackOverflow's md processor 

public class Article
{
    public string Headline { get; set; }
    public string Content
    {
        get
        {
            return _content;
        }
        set
        {
            var md = new Markdown();
            var html = md.Transform(value);
            _content = html;
        }       
    }
    private string _content;
    public DateTime Published { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: Better in this case is subjective without knowing any specific objectives. Basically they are all valid and pick your favorite based on readability, maintainability, and logic

Comment: "better ways" is subjective, for example, I would store content as original user input, just so they could edit it, but return Content converted to html..

Comment: Whenever you use the vague term _better_ you should think about if you have explained what you mean. Otherwise people will think that the question is opinion based and too broad to be answered.

Comment: "is the example acceptable use of the two ways" - it likely is not MEANT to be more than an example of the difference. Examples are simple because otherwise yxou hide the oint you want to demonstrate behind a lot of not relevant code. Do not interpret anything into an example it is not explicitly meant to demonstrate.

Comment: @TomTom I tried to provide some context also. Im just tinkering with asp as i try to learn C#, so this would be a model for a database. So there are endless ways of doing one thing, and it seems this way of using properties is correct, other than that a user would have to edit html instead of markdown as BugFinder said, great point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question *may* be better suited for codereview.stackexchange, although it's perhaps too tiny a snippet and to vague a question for that.

Personally, I shy away from magic properties that act in surprising ways. It tends to make for APIs that can be hard to use because they are surprising, even if they are somehow “clever” under the hood. You have a property where you set a different value than the one you get out. One thing where this can break would be the `+=` operator, which suddenly would work in very weird ways with your `Content` property.

I'd probably go with something like

```
public class Article
{
    private string content;
    private string renderedContent;

    public string Headline { get; set; }
    public string Content
    {
        get { return content; }
        set
        {
            content = value;
            renderedContent = null; // reset cached rendered content
        }
    }

    public string RenderedContent
    {
        get
        {
            if (renderedContent == null)
            {
                renderedContent = new Markdown().Transform(content);
            }
            return renderedContent;
        }
    }

    public DateTime Published { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

As for whether to use field-backed properties, or auto-properties, or computed properties ... that's up to you to decide based on what the property is supposed to do. Auto-properties are fine for simply storing and retrieving a value, e.g. `Published` or `Headline` here. You need the explicit backing field as soon as you do something more than just reading or writing it in the getter and setter, as shown here in `Content`. `RenderedContent` could be just a computed property, but I chose to cache the value after initial conversion because you kinda do the same. This pattern here doesn't convert the Markdown until it's actually needed, though.